# Visual studio Git Provider to Track rdl file

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

We are using Visual Studio 2012 to develop reports files (rdl files) and also use Microsoft Git provider to check files into TFS2013 Git repository.

Every time, when I work on C# files, I can see the files are checked out with "red flag" sign, however, I don't see this when I work on rdl file. Is there a setting that I can change to let Visual studio monitor the file changes I am making.

By the way, here is my .gitignore file.

```
#OS junk files
[Tt]humbs.db
*.DS_Store

#Visual Studio files
*.[Oo]bj
*.user
*.aps
*.pch
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ncb
*.suo
*.tlb
*.tlh
*.bak
*.[Cc]ache
*.ilk
*.log
*.lib
*.sbr
*.sdf
*.opensdf
*.unsuccessfulbuild
ipch/
obj/
[Bb]in
[Dd]ebug*/
[Rr]elease*/
Ankh.NoLoad
.idea/

#Tooling
_ReSharper*/
*.resharper
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*

#Project files
[Bb]uild/

#Subversion files
.svn

# Office Temp Files
~$*
Project.Web.Site/Web.config
```

Comment: It is weird I just made the test, I have VS 2012 tracking rdl files. I guess those files are not under any of these paths: ipch/
obj/ [Dd]ebug*/ [Rr]elease*/, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted a question on MSDN forum, looks like it's a [Visual Studio Git Provider](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dbb23ca8-ad22-438e-9cb1-513ee648e4c3/visual-studio-git-provider-to-track-rdl-file?forum=visualstudiogeneral#aa95c303-6648-4e7a-a081-d53b48e81112) bug.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have a .gitignore file in your repository.  The standard GitHub [Visual Studio .gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) file excludes *.rdl.data.

Comment: I mean the rdl file , not the rdl.data file.

Comment: Have you checked the .gitignore in your repository for *.rdl

Comment: Hmm clearly not it.  Under Team Explorer\Changes, is your rdl file in Untracked Files?

Comment: not sure where to find that settings, checked around, didn't see that settings

Comment: posted a question on msdn formu, looks like a bug of "Visual Stuido Git" provider